# SQLзапрос на сравнение двух групп сложных выборок

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужна помощь.

Не могу сформировать запрос в SQL.

Есть следующие таблицы:

```
Таблица t1 – таблица, с персональными данными о клиентах:

t1.account – номер счета;
t1.name – ФИО клиента;
t1.birthday – год рождения (DD/MM/YYYY).

Таблица t2 – таблица, с данными о заказах клиентов:

t2.account – номер счета;
t2.no_of_order – номер заказа;
t2.day_of_order – дата заказа (DD/MM/YYYY);
t2.invoice_amount – сумма заказа по ценам инвойса.
```

Необходимо написать запрос, результат которого – сравнение продаж клиентов в 2018 году против 2017 по группам за возрастом 18-23, 24-30, 31-45 и 46+.

Comment: *сравнение продаж клиентов* Критерий (формула) - где? сравнить - понятие широкое... больше-меньше устроит? вряд ли... По сути - используйте, например,  условную агрегацию.

Comment: @Akina имхо, категории в строки, годы в столбцы и все

Comment: @teran Ну если под сравнением имеется в виду "дайте пивот" - то, наверное, да. Тогда тем более условная агрегация (всё одно сумму считать).

Answer (score 1):

Примерно должен получится такой запрос:

```
select
sum(with_age.invoice_amount) sum_invoice_amount,
case
    when age >= 18 and age <= 23 then "18-23"
    when age >= 24 and age <= 30 then "24-30"
    when age >= 31 and age <= 45 then "31-45"
    when age >= 46 then "46+"
    else "N-A"
end age_category 

from (
    select
        t2.account,
        t2.invoice_amount,
    year(now()) - year(str_to_date(t1.birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')) age,
    from orders t2
    join accounts t1 on t1.account = t2.account
    where t2.day_of_order between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
) with_age
group by age_category
```

Comment: и где тут сравнение за 2017 и 2018 ? я бы сказал, что ожидается результат в виде - строки - категории возраста, и столбцы 2017 и 2018

Comment: @teran это подготовка выборки для сравнения за год. как должно сравниваться не указывалось. полагаю самый простейшим способом - это разница в сумме по возрастным категориям. тогда это просто на бекенде сделать + один запрос на след год.

Comment: либо создать таблицу, где будут агрегированные данные по годам и опираться на них при выводы. ну это уже зависит от задачи.

Comment: @Akina Да, спс. Не проверял, на скорую руку.